# std::count over variable string counting variable string

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm trying to write a function to parse xml returned to me from an api, the data returned is very variable, so I need to ensure this function will work in all cases.

Here is the start of the function where my error is occurring (I believe)

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> grabXMLVals(string xmlString, string toFind){
    vector<string> values;
    int amount = (int)count(xmlString.begin(), xmlString.end(), &toFind); 
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
```

I want to count the amount of times the toFind string occurs in xmlString to know how many times my loop needs to run.

but when I compile with the count statement as is I get :

```
Error   1   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> ' to 'int'  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility   3078
```

Not sure which param it is not happy with, pretty sure its not the third because If I give a hardcoded constant it still is not happy, but I've found lots of people using `std::count` with `std::string::begin` and end online while searching for my answer, what are they doing that I'm not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `toFind` is an `std::string` and `&toFind` takes its address. So what you are doing is this:

```
std::string const* addr = &toFind;
std::find (xmlString.begin(), xmlString.end(), addr);
```

So you are trying to find a pointer inside a `std::string` which doesn't work.

What you want is something like this:

```
std::size_t count_substr(std::string const& str, std::string const& toFind)
{
    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::size_t pos = 0;

    while(pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        pos = str.find (toFind, pos);

        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            /* increment the count */            
            count++;

            /* skip the instance of the string we just found */
            pos++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

This is not the most elegant thing, but it should get you what you need.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That was my backup plan but I have a bit of an irrational fear of while(1) loops.

Comment: Updated to *not* have a `while(1)` loop.

Comment: We can shorten it to `while(std::string::npos != (pos = str.find(toFind, pos))) count++,pos++;` :-)

Comment: It may be relevant to do `pos += toFind.size()` instead of `pos++`.

Comment: @nodakai `for(std::string::size_type pos = 0; std::string::npos != (pos = str.find(toFind, pos)); ++count, ++pos);` is even more incomprehensible.